# toString() no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, overriding, tostring

I'm banging my head here..

Given in C#...

```
public class ClassA
{
    public override string toString()
    {
        return "use this toString()!";
    }
}
```

When I try to build this it tells me: "ClassA.toString(): no suitable method found to override."

How do you override the default toString in C# if not this?

Comment: Well, C# != Java. Methods in .NET typically starts with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct method is `ToString`

Comment: I've tried that too.  toString() gives me the error.  ToString() just gives me the default behavior.  I must be doing something else wrong here.

Comment: @confusedWithJava - The capitalisation is the only problem with the code you've posted. `new ClassA().ToString()` will return "use this toString()!"

Comment: I'll have to keep looking to figure out what's going on then.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 3):

It's ToString (with a capital T) that you're after. Contrary to other languages such as Java, C# generally has method names starting with capitals. And like other languages such as Java, it is case sensitive!

Are you coming from a Java background by any chance? :-)